# "UnrecognizedURLError" ember startup probs

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Using http://localhost:4200/index.html as the base URL,
need to route to dashboard on load of my application ..added route for dashboard in router.js

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  The best questions here include a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.  Until you include more of your code, it's anybody's guess about what your problem could be.  Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

In router.js file,

```
this.route('dashboard', { path: '/' });
```

This will always redirect `/` route to dashboard route.

Answer (score 0):

Your baseUrl shouldn't point to the index.html file. It should rather simply be '/' if possible. That way, your application is served on http://localhost:4200/, no `index` or `.html` is needed in the url.

If you want this route to redirect to `/dashboard`, go to `routes/application.js` and add the following function:

```
didTransition() {
  this.transitionTo('dashboard');
}
```

That way, when the base route has transitioned, it'll "redirect" to dashboard.

Comment: There is the issue of hosting several emberjs apps in a single server, so your suggestion is not feasable in that case.